# Issue with multiple loops and pushing to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am using Angular/Typescript with the amcharts library (version 4), specifically the multi line graph. In building the chart data, it only seems to work correctly with a single push to the chart array.

Here is my code:

```
 chart.data = [];

        let hvacData: any = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < this.chartTradeData['HVAC'].length; i++) {
          const newDate = new Date(this.chartTradeData['HVAC'][i]['calendarDate']);
          hvacData = this.chartTradeData['HVAC'][i]['revWorkDay'];
          hvacData = parseInt(hvacData);
          chart.data.push({
            date: newDate,
            hvacData
          });
        }

        let plumbingData: any = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < this.chartTradeData['Plumbing'].length; i++) {
          const newDate = new Date(this.chartTradeData['Plumbing'][i]['calendarDate']);
          plumbingData = this.chartTradeData['Plumbing'][i]['revWorkDay'];
          plumbingData = parseInt(plumbingData);
          chart.data.push({
            date: newDate,
            plumbingData
          });
        }

        let electricalData: any = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < this.chartTradeData['Electrical'].length; i++) {
          const newDate = new Date(this.chartTradeData['Electrical'][i]['calendarDate']);
          electricalData = this.chartTradeData['Electrical'][i]['revWorkDay'];
          electricalData = parseInt(electricalData);
          chart.data.push({
            date: newDate,
            electricalData
          });
        }
```

Doing it as above only renders the first line on the graph. I need to figure out how to do all these pushes at once so that it looks like this after the loops:

```
  chart.data.push({
        date: newDate,
        hvacData,
        plumbingData,
        electricalData
      });
    }
```

The object I am iterating over looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Your code seems to be just pushing data into the array instead of looking up for an item that is already in the array that has the same `date`, and then updating that.

Comment: any ideas on a way to achieve this? There are multiple arrays...and they may or may not be the same length and have the same calendar date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [addData](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychart/#addData_method) method:

```
chart.addData([...]);
```

I recommend you to try add arrays with all the data instead of one item at a time.

Check more about [incremental updates](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Incremental_updates) here.